# How do I call a model dynamically? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, activerecord

I'm trying to call a model dynamically.

I cam across this [solution](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/88936/#449386):

```
$fred = $type.'_model';

$this->load->model($fred);
$this->$fred->get();
```

Which works but I was wondering how to do this with a class variable i.e. something simllar to:

```
$this->fred = $type.'_model';
```

but I'm not sure how to use it like the first example.. anyone able to help?

**Edit:**

I've used it like this but I'm not sure if it's the best solution?

```
$this->{$this->fred}->get();
```

Comment: Yeah that is correct the way you used. Are you facing any issue with that ?

Comment: the way you used it in the edit is correct :)

Comment: The best way I have found to load model dynamically. Across website is to set it up in libraries folder and convert model to library format. Or if you have multiple CI installs put it in the systems libraries folder then autoload it.